# Retreive ComboBox selection and write to a cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop, combobox

the following code summarizes what I need to do, where I have four comboboxes inside a userform: options1, options2, nights1 and nights2. Options contain string information and nights contain numbers.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 2
        Me.Controls("options" & CStr(i)).AddItem "Option 1"
        Me.Controls("options" & CStr(i)).AddItem "Option 2"
        Me.Controls("nights" & CStr(i)).AddItem "1"
        Me.Controls("nights" & CStr(i)).AddItem "2"

     Next i
End Sub

Private Sub btnEnd_Click()
    Dim options(1 To 2) As String
    Dim nights(1 To 2) As Integer

    For i = 1 To 2
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, i + 1) = options(i)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, i + 1) = nights(i)

    Next i
End Sub
```

I need the selected option from my comboboxes to be written into specified cells, been getting all sorts of different results with the current one being blank values in option cells and 0s in night cells. I am fairly new to VBA so I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: ```btnEnd_Click``` you create two arrays but never populate them, so they contain blank strings and 0s respectively as that is the default value for their types.

Comment: How could I populate them from the selected values in each combobox?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can populate the combo boxes:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    '~~~> Add items to the combobox.
    cb1.List = Array("red", "blue")
    cb2.List = Array(1, 2)

    End Sub
```

** Note, you have the values for the 2nd combobox listed as integers, so do not wrap the numbers in quotation marks.

This is how you can retrieve the combo box values and write them to cells.

```
Private Sub cmdBtn_Click()


'~~~> Declare the data types for the variables.
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSheet As String
Dim lrow_cb1 As Long
Dim lrow_cb2 As Long
Dim lcol As Long
Dim rng_cb1 As Range
Dim rng_cb2 As Range

'~~~> Assign objects/values to the variables.
strSheet = "Sheet1"
lrow_cb1 = 2
lrow_cb2 = 3
lcol = 0
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(strSheet)


'~~~> When the command button is clicked, write the cb1 and cb2 values to.....

'~~~> cb1 contains strings and cb2 contains integers
'~~~> cb1 to A2; cb2 to A3

'~~~> Start the column index.
lcol = lcol + 1

'~~~> Set the range variables.
Set rng_cb1 = ws.Cells(lrow_cb1, lcol)
Set rng_cb2 = ws.Cells(lrow_cb2, lcol)


'~~~> Assign the combobox selections to cells.
rng_cb1.Value = Me.cb1.Text
rng_cb2.Value = Me.cb2.Value


'~~~> Release the variables.
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
strWS = vbNullString
lrow_cb1 = vbNull
lrow_cb2 = vbNull
lcol = vbNull
Set rng_cb1 = Nothing
Set rng_cb2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Call the user form with a button click from the worksheet.

```
Private Sub cb_ShowUF_Click()

Call uf_ComboBox.Show

End Sub
```

[image]